# How to get absolutely reproducible results with Scikit Learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-seed

Regarding the seeding system when running machine learning algorithms with `Scikit-Learn`, there are three different things usually mentioned:

- `random.seed`
- `np.random.seed`
- `random_state` at `SkLearn` (cross-validation iterators, ML algorithms etc)

I have already in my mind this [FAQ](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-set-a-random-state-for-an-entire-execution) of `SkLearn` about how to fix the global seeding system and [articles](https://mikulskibartosz.name/how-to-set-the-global-random-state-in-scikit-learn-d27f267622a2) which point out that this should not be simply a FAQ.

My ultimate question is how can I get absolutely reproducible results when running an ML algorithm with `SkLearn`?

In more detail,

- If I only use `np.random.seed` and do not specify any `random_state` at `SkLearn` then will my results be absolutely reproducible?

and one question at least for the sake of knowledge:

- How exactly `np.random.seed` and `random_state`of `SkLearn` are internally related? How `np.random.seed` affects the seeding system (`random_state`) of `SkLearn` and makes it (at least hypothetically speaking) to reproduce the same results?

Answer (score 7):

Defining random seed will make sure that every time you run the algorithm, the random will generate the same numbers. IMHO, the result will always be the same as long as we use the same data, and the same values of any other parameters.

As you have read in sklearn's FAQ, it is the same either you define it globally by `numpy.random.seed()` or by set `random_state` parameter in all algorithms involved, provided that you set the same number for both cases.

I take example from sklearn [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), to illustrate it.

```
import numpy
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# numpy.random.seed(42)
X, y = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)

#1 running this many times, Xtr will remain [[4, 5],[0, 1],[6, 7]].
Xtr, Xte, ytr, yte = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

#2 try running this line many times, you will get various Xtr
Xtr, Xte, ytr, yte = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)
```

Now uncomment the third line. Run #2 many times. `Xtr` will always be `[[4, 5],[0, 1],[6, 7]]`

By `numpy.random.seed()`, it sets seed to default (None) and then it will try to read data from /dev/urandom (or the Windows analogue) if available or seed from the clock otherwise. [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html#numpy.random.RandomState)

Comment: Yes, it is actually clearer to me now that "whenever a RandomState instance or an integer random seed is not provided as an argument, it relies on the numpy global random state, which can be set using `numpy.random.seed`".

Comment: However, one question of mine is: if you have not set any value to `numpy.random.seed` then it simply picks one in a random way by itself?

Comment: Yes it will pick a value, but of course not in random way. How do you imagine ‘random’ in computer?. So if you don’t define seed, then it will use ,for example, current timestamp as seed. That’s why you will get different numbers when you generate it now and later.

Comment: Apparently I am talking about this kind of randomness (like picking a numpy seed value according to a "random" element like timestamps etc). However, do we know that it uses timestamps?

Comment: @PoeteMaudit if part of the answer doesn't answer your question please address this in a comment to the author, suggesting an edit to remove it is not the correct course of action

Comment: @PoeteMaudit , https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html#numpy.random.RandomState

Comment: Ok cool. So if you want, remove the `pickle` part from your post (because my question is about the seeding systems) and add in a well presentable way some of the things that we have discussed here in the comments and then I will tick your answer as correct. For now +1 for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

In scikit-learn documentation examples, for instance [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_iris.html), they use `np.random.seed(n)` which seems to work.

Comment: Cool but I expect a more thorough analysis of the seeding system of sklearn and numpy from an answer on StackOverflow.

Comment: While this link may assist in your answer to the question, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)

Answer (score 0):

I just was playing with `numpy` and as well with `sklearn`. Apparently, setting `np.random.seed` does not guarantee a fixed random state for `sklearn`. We need to set `random_state` parameter corresponding to each `sklearn` function to ensure repeatability.